# Draw on CartesianDataCanvas item that larger than the chart

Tags: apache-flex, charts, drawing

I want to draw on a Flex AreaChart. This AreaChart has an AnnotationElement that is an CartesianDataCanvas.
When I draw some items on this CartesianDataCanvas, the chart looks good when the item fits inside the chart. 
But when I draw an item that is bigger than the chart, the chart automatically resize and try to fit my item inside the chart. I dont want my chart to resize automatically like that, but rather not showing the item part lay outside the chart. What should I do?

Thank you a lot,
Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about scaling it manually?

before you draw it on the canvas, determine the sizes of AreaChart including width/percentWidth and same for height, and scale your graphics to fit the canvas/AreaChart.

If you want to do it right, research this canvas to next properties:

`explicitMaxWidth` and `postLayoutTransformOffsets` and this too `setLayoutBoundsPosition   ()` from documentation about AreaChart & CartesianDataCanvas

And let us know :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution :)
I finally find out a way. There are so many properties and method associated with each Flex components, after searching around I found properties x and y of HitData object. I will my item based on that coordinators x and y.
How do you get to know those properties like explicitMaxWidth? There are too many of them, the extends and implements hierarchy is also very complicated.

Comment: great choice Henry, if your graphic you drawing is really less than canvas sizes, in my answer I also proposed an idea how to fit it if it bigger than sizes of canvas. Anyway, I very like flex, and imho we could do anything we want using this platform )